# 301 Redirect to subfolder but with input

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want my wordpress site redirections to remember the url but place it in a subfolder.

So http://www.example.com/test123 has to redirect to http://www.example.com/voetbal/test123

And http://www.example.com/0239 to http://www.example.com/voetbal/0239

My htaccess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /voetbal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /voetbal/index.php [R=301, L]
```

this makes my site go from http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com/voetbal/
but only the root.

How can i make my htaccess to remember peoples input and place it after the /voetbal/

Comment: Are you sending *all* requests to the one subfolder? If so, why? Or is there other content at, e.g. `http://www.example.com/other-folder/`?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /voetbal%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again. the Redirect is working fine on my server.

Comment: "try"... code-only answers are not very helpful.  Why does this work? Also, this doesn't appear to be a WP-friendly rewrite rule....

Comment: Hmm weird, i tried emptying my cache and even on incognite mode this still only works for the base url.